# How to limit "drush pm-updatestatus" to check only given project?

Tags: drush

When I run the `drush pm-updatestatus drupal` it keeps checking all other projects like:

```
drush pm-updatestatus drupal
Checking available update data ...                                                                                                  [ok]
Checking available update data for Drupal.                                                                                          [ok]
Checking available update data for Views Bulk Operations (views_bulk_operations).                                                   [ok]
Checking available update data for AddThis (addthis).                                                                               [ok]
Checking available update data for Administration views (admin_views).                                                              [ok]
Checking available update data for BeautyTips API (beautytips).                                                                     [ok]
Checking available update data for BUEditor (bueditor).                                                                             
Checking available update data for Date (date).                                                                                     [ok]
Checking available update data for @font-your-face (fontyourface).                                                                  [ok]
Checking available update data for Entity API (entity).                                                                             [ok]
Checking available update data for FAQ Field (faqfield).                                                                            [ok]
Checking available update data for Features (features).                                                                             [ok]
Checking available update data for Feeds (feeds).                                                                                   [ok]
Checking available update data for File Entity (file_entity).                                                                       [ok]
Checking available update data for File Field Sources (filefield_sources).                                                          [ok]
Checking available update data for Google reCAPTCHA (google_recaptcha).                                                             [ok]
Checking available update data for Gravatar (gravatar).                                                                             [ok]
Checking available update data for Insert (insert).                                                                                 [ok]
Checking available update data for Job Scheduler (job_scheduler).                                                                   [ok]
Checking available update data for jQuery Update (jquery_update).                                                                   [ok]
Checking available update data for Libraries (libraries).                                                                           [ok]
Checking available update data for Mailhandler (mailhandler).                                                                       [ok]
Checking available update data for Mail System (mailsystem).                                                                        [ok]
Checking available update data for Media (media).                                                                                   [ok]
Checking available update data for Memcache (memcache).                                                                             [ok]
Checking available update data for Metatag (metatag).                                                                               [ok]
Checking available update data for Mime Mail (mimemail).                                                                            [ok]
Checking available update data for MultiBlock (multiblock).                                                                         [ok]
Checking available update data for OAuth (oauth).                                                                                   [ok]
Checking available update data for Extended Path Aliases (path_alias_xt).                                                           [ok]
Checking available update data for Pathauto (pathauto).                                                                             [ok]
```

Is there an alternative to `drush pm-updatestatus` or a way to make it check only the given project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `drush pm-updatestatus` is so noisy, the "Checking available update data" output is IMHO debug output that shouldn't be displayed, I often use `drush pm-releases` (rl) in stead. The drawback with using `drush rl` is that it always produces output - you need to read, and optionally check that "Installed" and "Recommended" is on the same line.

Another work-around is to throw away the debug output:

```
drush pm-updatestatus MODULE 2> /dev/null
```